# Copy content://mms-sms/conversations to SD card

Tags: android

I would like to copy the entire contents of the mms-sms database to the SD card, but I can't find a way of doing so. I'd preferably also like to avoid iterating through the entire database (a few calls to the database querying excluded from this exception).

I have already added the R/W External Storage permissions and the R/W SMS permissions.

Can this be done without rooting and copying mmssms.db?

---

Extra Details: I'm using API level 21 (Lollipop 5.0+) and I'd also need a way of restoring the copy from the SD card to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very API Level dependent since Android opened up in Level 19.

`Telephony.Sms` and `Telephony.Mms` have `Inbox` and `Outbox` classes that contain all the SMS and MMS messages on the device

Comment: Since I'm using this program to back them up, I'd also need a way of restoring the backup. I'm using API level 21 (yes, I know that not many phones run Lollipop but I'm doing this for personal use)

Comment: But how would I poll all the SMS and MMS threads and later on restore them from a file? I know that this involves querying the CONTENT_URI but the question is... What do I do once I've created the Cursor? I've never used Cursors before.